# How to get view block content by drupal8

Tags: php, drupal, mpdf

I am completing a requirement: display the results in a column chart after statistics, and export the column chart as a PDF file; now my column chart has been created using google charts to create a view, and I now want to use mPDF to convert the column The chart is exported as a PDF file, but the html code content of the column chart is needed here, how can I get the html content of this column chart in php programming? Please help me, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question need to include a [**Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to focus on your issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.